# Upload Image in Database (MySql) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly tell me what is the best method of storing images in database.

1. Storing Images into database

OR

2. Uploading images to a folder and save the image path into the database for extracting it for later use.

If some one provide me a demo also with a form having two input fields of text and option of attaching image also and providing sql queries for uploading the record into database will help me a lot in understanding. I have little knowledge in this field. I m in learning process. Kindly help me

Comment: Save the image path. There are a truckload of demos on the web, SO is *not* a coding service. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most commonly used method is to save the image path to the database and the actual image to a directory. This is just a demo of what I currently use.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$target_dir = 'PATH/TO/SAVE/IT/TO/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

// If Its Empty Throw Error
if (basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]) == "") {
    // Error Code Here
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
}else{
    // Throw Error Here
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    // Throw Error Here
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > $max_image_size) {
    // Throw Error Here
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    // Throw Error Here
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 1) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        // DB Insert HERE
    }else{
        // Throw Error Here
    }
}
```

Outputting the image:

PHP:

```
function getUserImage() {
    $uid = $_SESSION['user'];   
    $query = "SELECT `image` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?"; 
    $params = array($uid); 
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    return $results[0]['image'];
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="images/users/<?php echo getUserImage(); ?>" />
```

Comment: Make sure where you are storing it that it is varchar or something that excepts different char types.